# Meaning of "The other right" and "back looping"

Tags: vocabulary, spoken-english, terminology, literature

I was watching the sci-fi series "The Flash".

Character1 is instructing Character2 about direction:

> Character1: "Turn right"
> *Charater2 moves in the wrong direction.*
> Charater1: "No, the other right."

How could Character2 move to the "other right"? This was a lane. One can only move to the right or the left. But when Charater1 said "The other right", Charater2 went to the opposite side.

Is a way in English where the left side is also called "The other right"?

Another confusion is the meaning of the sentence "I am back looping security camera."

In the scene, Charater1 disabled all the CCTV using a software. I know "loopback" is coined from the vocabulary of computer science. But what does it mean in the English language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The other right" (or "the other left") is a jokey way of telling someone that they got confused and turned the wrong way.  Quoting from the [TV Tropes website](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/YourOtherLeft):

> If ever in a comedy somebody tells a character or a group of characters to move/turn left, you can bet the character/one or more of the group will go right instead, prompting the phrase, "Your *other* left!".

TV Tropes claims that this is *always* done with the "other left" and *never* with the "other right," but that is obviously wrong since you found a counterexample.  This joke is super common (at least in America) and most native speakers will have heard it since childhood.

---

As for your other question, the idea of "looping" a recording is far older than computer programming.  It dates to the days of magnetic tape, when a [tape loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tape_loop) was an actual loop of physical audio or video tape that would play the same sequence over and over again forever.

In the show, the character is saying that he is *looping* the video feed *back* into the past, so that anyone watching will be seeing old footage instead of whatever or whoever is in view of the camera now.